# Toggler não funciona

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, django

Estou estudando Django e encontrei o seguinte problema ao usar os staticsfiles, o toggler que aparece quando a tela é reduzida não extende minha navbar do bootstrap, não encontrei o erro.

OBS: o resto funciona, dropdown, navbar (css/js)

OBS1: quando eu uso CDN funciona tudo, inclusive o toggler

apresenta esse erro: "Uncaught TypeError: collapse.js:346 to primitive value."

aqui tem os trechos que eu chamo os staticsfiles e o link do projeto completo no github

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
)
```

**scripts.html**

```
{% load static %}

<script src="{% static 'jquery/dist/jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js'%}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
```

[Projeto no Github](https://github.com/ChenGit55/LASE)

Comment: Dá uma olhada no console do navegador (usando por exemplo o Chrome DevTools) para ver se todos arquivos são carregados e se há algum erro. Se houver algum erro, complemente sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz o que Thiago Krempser sugeriu e acabei descobrindo que a versão 3.5.0 do jQuery está apresentando problemas, fiz um downgrade pra versão 3.4.1 (a mesma que é usada via CDN) e tudo funcionou!